# How to add century values (i.e. 1900 and 2000) to decade years in a pandas column0

Tags: python, pandas

This should be simple: I have a column in a pandas data frame. The column has values 91 to 99 (for years 1991 to 1999) and values 00 to 17 for years of this century.

I now use this very long code to add 1900 and 2000 to values from last, respectively this century.

```
df['year2'] = df.year
df.loc[df.year>20, 'year2']=df.loc[df.year>20, 'year']+1900
df.loc[df.year<20, 'year2']=df.loc[df.year<20, 'year']+2000
df['year']=df['year2']
df.drop(columns=['year2']
```

I am sure this can be done more efficiently.

Comment: Don't use 2-digit years in the first place. That's just reintroducing the Y2K bug. Besides, the cutoff is a bit arbitrary. How would you handle WW I data with such a rule? How about data about the Spanish flue pandemic? Different applications use different rules but most of them put the cutoff decades in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'year':[91,99,1,15,17,93],
         'A':[7,8,9,4,2,3],

})

df['year1'] = np.where(df['year']>20, df['year']+1900, df['year']+2000)
print (df)
   year  A  year1
0    91  7   1991
1    99  8   1999
2     1  9   2001
3    15  4   2015
4    17  2   2017
5    93  3   1993
```

If strings column:

```
y = df['year'].astype(int)
df['year1'] = np.where(y>20, y+1900, y+2000)
```

**Performance**:

```
np.random.seed(123)

N = 1000
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'year':np.random.randint(1, 99, size=N),
})


In [55]: %timeit df['year1'] = np.where(df['year']>20, df['year']+1900, df['year']+2000)
615 µs ± 79.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [58]: %timeit df['year2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year'].astype(str).str.zfill(2), format='%y').dt.year
3.49 ms ± 31.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**Performance for strings column**:

```
N = 1000
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'year':np.random.randint(1, 99, size=N),
})

df['year'] = df['year'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
print (df.head())
  year
0   36
1   55
2   39
3   05
4   55
```

---

```
In [80]: %%timeit
    ...: y = df['year'].astype(int)
    ...: df['year1'] = np.where(y>20, y+1900, y+2000)
    ...: 
761 µs ± 14.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [81]: %%timeit
    ...: df['year2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year'], format='%y').dt.year
    ...: 
2.33 ms ± 44.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

`pandas.to_datetime` will handle this.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame({'year':['91', '95', '05', '99', '13', '17']})

df['year2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year'], format='%y').dt.year
print(df['year2'])
```

Output:

```
0    1991
1    1995
2    2005
3    1999
4    2013
5    2017
```

Comment: It seems there are integers, then need `df['year2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year'].astype(str).str.zfill(2), format='%y').dt.year`

Comment: `python 3` doesn't allow integers to start with 0 so I am not sure how it will represent 00 or 01 as int.

Comment: I think integers, because `df.loc[df.year>20, 'year2']=df.loc[df.year>20, 'year']+1900` not working with strings.

Comment: Initially I thought the column must be integer but then I realized we can not have leading 0 in int values so I went with string values. Maybe OP can clarify this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get this back:  time data '0' does not match format '%y' (match)

Comment: @MartienLubberink  because you have 0 instead of 00 in your data. Try using @jezrael 's `np.where` solution, it will work in your case